# Mirth Connect PID-2

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a source transformation for PID-2 that i need the external ID to be populated. But this ID is on a different SQL Server database table sitting on another server. Is there a code i could get to retrieve and populate this field.

I had this but i know there is something more that needs to be done:

```
var strConn = "driver={sql server};server=servername;database=database;uid=us ername;password=password"; 
var strQuery = "SELECT INTERNALID FROM EXTID where msg['record_number'].toString() = INTERNALID"; 

var cnt = result.size();    //get the number of rows returned in the query 
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) 

{     //loop it up 
    result.next();      //go to the first row 

    var INTERNALID = result.getString(1); 
}
```

What am trying to do is append PID-2 on destination HL7 file where record_number on host server is equal to record number on foreign sql server.
my result should be inserted in tmp['PID']['PID.2']['PID.2.1']

So the code should look at the "record_number" in PID-3 and get the corresponding ID (INTERNALID) on SQL server and append to PID-2 on my destination file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **DatabaseConnection** object to execute your query and grab your results.

```
var dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('driver', 'address', 'username', 'password');
```

You can then execute a parameterized database query like so

```
var paramList = new java.util.ArrayList();
paramList.add(msg['PID']['PID.3']['PID.3.1'].toString());
var expression = "SELECT internal_id FROM your_table WHERE record_number = ?";
result = dbConn.executeCachedQuery('expression', paramList);
```

From there, if you just want to grab the first row then you can do the following

```
if (result.next()) {
    var internalID = result.getString(1);
}
```

I made a bunch of assumptions about your column names and such but the workflow should be similar